# How can I disable voice commands when double pressing the home button on the Galaxy S 4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, voice-command

How do I disable the Voice Command on my Galaxy 4s when pressing the Home key twice?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a function of S Voice, which can be activated with the Home key. To disable it, open S Voice, and open its application settings.

Uncheck 'Open via the Home key'.

See this article at [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/galaxy-s4-quick-tip-disable-s-voice-shortcut-faster-home-button-response).